# Different line spacing in text and footnotes when using \usepackage[para]{footmisc}

Tags: footnotes, line-spacing, setspace, footmisc

Hope this hasn't already been addressed:

I would like my linespacing in the footnotes to be small whilst having double or more linespace in the text. I've been using `\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}` and `\usepackage[para]{footmisc}` in order to have as many footnotes on the same line as possible. The problem is that `\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}` should only change the text body and not the footnotes but that is not the case in my file.

[This](http://osksn2.hep.sci.osaka-u.ac.jp/%7Enaga/miscellaneous/tex/images/tex-tips/footmisc.pdf) link says "Footmisc knows about this [my problem], and preserves the change. However, you
must load setspace before footmisc." Maybe I don't understand what 'load' means, but I can't seem to make it work, even if I make a new file and compile it in the suggested order.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what the problem might be, or to try different packages?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of adding `doublespacing` as the option to `setspace`, add it after the `\begin{document}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{setspace}                    %%% not in the option
\usepackage[para]{footmisc}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}   %% for dummy text

\begin{document}
\doublespacing                           %%% add it here
\kant[1]

Some text here\footnote{first foot note} some more text here\footnote{\kant[1]}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can still load it in the preamble, just *after* footmisc has been loaded: `\usepackage{setspace} \usepackage[para]{footmisc} \doublespacing`.  Whether you want to do so, I suppose, depends on whether there is 'frontmatter' (etc.) material that needs to be single spaced.